# Matlab error with Gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am trying to link a slider and an editable text box and I am getting this error and I do not know why.

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

```
Error in ImageProcTool>sliderthresh_Callback (line 110)  
textValue = handles.sliderthresh.Value;

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ImageProcTool (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in  
@(hObject,eventdata)ImageProcTool('sliderthresh_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Without your code it's hard to tell but the first line should give you a good clue. It says you're treating something that's not a structure as one - check if you're calling anything like `structure.property` where you don't intend to.

Comment: Wild guess: replace the line `textValue = handles.sliderthresh.Value;` with `textValue = get(handles.sliderthresh,'Value');`.